# Procedure to extract multiple select query result to a single insert statement

Tags: java, sql, function, stored-procedures

Scenario is to execute Select query from 9 different tables in Sec region and extract all the obtained results into a .txt file as insert statement's (with few schema details modified) and the purpose is to run them in Sec1 region to bring Sec data to sec1 region for analysis & pit work. Is there a way to write a java program to invoke a DB call to do this by giving the select query inputs. in this i have jus 2 input parameter for all the 9 select statements.

Since i am doing it for my uni project it would helpful if reply is little descriptive and elaborate.

Comment: Even if it were clear, this question would be way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the 9 tables are in the same schema, it might be possible to use just one large query instead of 9 smaller ones. However, we'd need to know more details in order to be able to confirm this.